# Accessing Comments via Gdata API

Tags: google-docs, gdata, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

**Question 1**: How can I access comments via gdata api for Google Document?

Can somebody provide me a sample code or link to some documentation?
Is that possible?

**Question 2**: How can manage (reply, add, resolve ...) Google Document via gdata api?

Can somebody provide me a sample code or link to some documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no GData API to access comments in a Google document.

You can use the Document services in Apps Script to programmatically access the content of a document from your script:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_document